# Hide/Unhide rows based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need an assistance for my issue. How to include two different criterias into this code to make my rows hidden/unhiden, if I one criteria is TRUE/FALSE and another is Drop-down with some values?
For the first criteria, with True/False, if the True is selected then hide all False rows, and for another criteria where I have drop-down, the only thing I wanted to have is when I choose 0 as a value to unhide all rows, to bring back my original state of data.

p.s True/False rows is a "helper column" where I am actually filter another values (from drop down). If I choose TRUE then I am having all needed values and if it is FALSE then I am excluding them from the list.

```
Sub Hide_Unhide_Rows()

  If Range("B3").Value = "Passed" Then
    Rows("5:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ElseIf Range("B3").Value = "Failed" Then
    Rows("5:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your post has no question, you need to ask one (see [ask]). Also you should explain what you tried and what the issue is that stops you from writing that code. A list of requirements is not actually a question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ check it now, better explanation

Comment: Please, clarify what "all False rows" means.

Comment: Either use filters (because that is what you are actually trying to do) or you somehow need to loop through your rows to check which are false and hide each one of them. But you need to come up with some attempt or you need to explain why you could not accomplish it and where exactly you got stuck. • Otherwise this is a *"here is my code please fix it for me"* question.

Comment: @FaneDuru I put an explanation...

Comment: @Mirza Digg into how to use the [Range.AutoFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter).

Answer (score 0):

### Toggle Hide/Unhide

- Adjust the `Range("B3")` and the constants in the second procedure.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("B3"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        toggleHide Range("B3")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub toggleHide(ByVal CellRange As Range)
    
    Const RowsAddress As String = "5:10"
    Const cCol As String = "G"
    Const Crit As Boolean = False
    
    With CellRange.Worksheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Rows(RowsAddress)
        
        Select Case CellRange.Value
        Case "Hide"
            Dim drg As Range
            Set drg = rg.Columns(cCol).Offset(-1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count + 1)
            drg.AutoFilter 1, Crit
            If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, drg) > 1 Then
                Dim frg As Range: Set frg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                frg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Case "Show"
            rg.Hidden = False
        'Case Else
        End Select
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hmmm, something is wrong, actually I changed all "Const" but nothing is working...or I didnt understand it properly. So in "G3" I should have TRUE/FALSE? 
Column G by me is full of TRUE/FALSE instances, but it is not reacting when I select on or another.

Comment: `B3` contains a dropdown containing `Hide` and `Show`. As you choose one of them, the rows containing `FALSE` in columns `G` automatically get hidden, or all rows get shown.

Comment: Hmm I got it but it is not functioning...is it matter if in Column G are values (TRUE and FALSE) derived from formulas?

Comment: In the Module or Sheet?

Comment: No, I was wrong. The event depends only on cell `B3`. Is this all happening in one worksheet? Did you put the event code in the sheet module of the sheet where `B3` is located?

Comment: Ye in one sheet only. I put Sheet Module (Sheet1) on sheet...and module is in module as you wrote above...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's happening. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FPxcesg7JZqxHikVjpfkuvu927tldJLS/view?usp=sharing) is a copy of my workbook on `Google Drive`. You have to download it to use it (down arrow at the top-right). I would appreciate it if you would share what was (or still is) wrong.

Comment: Your is good but mine got now first time error on "drg. AutoFilter 1, Crit" 
I am not limited to 5:10 rows btw., it can and will be 100+...

Comment: So calculate the last row, you know the drill: `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row` and later use `Set rg = .Rows("5:" & LastRow)`. There's nothing to it. Also, the first row has to be greater than 1, because `AutoFilter` needs a header row.

Comment: Hmm same error afterwards... i don’t get the whole code unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, I tried on your Workbook to add more values (TRUE/FALSE) but it is limited to 6 rows only, it is not working properly if I add XY of them.

Comment: If have mood maybe you can jump in and add what is necessary. I am not a VBA master...not at all.